# Is the facebooker plugin still applicable for developing FBConnect applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebooker

Im trying to integrate FBConnect to my application and want to know if the facebooker plugin is still applicable now that Facebook has made some revisions to its API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, but you should still test the functionality you plan on using. Also, Facebook's API is known to return bad data, claim that access tokens are invalid, or lots of other things. So, be sure to take a look at the exceptions that Facebooker raises and handle them.

Comment: I ended up using the FaceBook Javascript API. Thanks and sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I just ran through this tutuorial on how to integrate restful_authentication and facebook connect using the facebooker gem. It works great :) http://madebymany.co.uk/tutorial-for-restful_authentication-on-rails-with-facebook-connect-in-15-minutes-00523